# Pointing purchased domain to a subdomain on an another hosting (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, web, subdomain

I bought a domain (www.domain.com) with godaddy.ca. Just the domain without the hosting.
I created a Wordpress website on a subdomain (sub.mydomain.it) on another hosting (Netsons).
Now I need to point the domain to the subdomain. 
I tried the forwarding with masking through GoDaddy DNS Management, and it works. If I go to www.domain.com it redirects me as needed. I can see the content of the website on my subdomain.
Anyway, I still have all the internal links that show my subdomain.

How can I solve this?
Thank you for your help and sorry for the rough English.
I really appreciate.

Comment: You could either do a domain transfer or point your domain name to your hosting account, check your hosting providers FAQ's they usually have this explained in detail. Third option is to contact the hosting company's support and have them guide you or do it for you.

Comment: You need to fix your website code, use relative URLs